# Error al crear suscripciòn en MercadoPago

Tags: mercadopago

Buenas noches.

Estoy intentando crear una suscripciòn a un plan en Mercado Pago. El proceso lo realize antes con exito, pero desde hoy que arroja el siguiente error:

```
{"status"=>"500",
  "response"=>
    {"message"=>"Internal Server Error",
     "error"=>"unauthorized_scopes",
     "status"=>500,
     "cause"=>
     [{"code"=>2, "description"=>"Internal Server Error", "data"=>nil}]}}
```

Quiero saber si es un error al enviar los datos de la suscripciòn o es algo interno de MercadoPago.

Segun la api de mercado libre mi aplicaciòn tiene los siguientes scopes:

```
"scopes": [
  "write",
  "offline_access",
  "read"
]
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.